# Валидация xml файла

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, xsd

Есть xml файл. Его необходимо проверить согласнo схеме XSD.

Вот такой простенький код:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("file.xml");

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("schema.xsd");
XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(reader, null);
document.Schemas.Add(schema);

document.Validate((o, e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); });
```

Если в схеме импортируются другие схемы, то возникает exception с примерно следующим содержанием:

> Undefined complexType 'ТУТ СОБСТВЕННО ТИП, КОТОРЫЙ В ОПИСАН В ИМПОРТИРУЕМОЙ СХЕМЕ' is used as a base for complex type extension.`

Импортируемая схема лежит рядом с schema.xsd, `schemaLocation` указана.

Разве импортируемая схема не должна была подхватиться? Как это исправить?

Кстати, если попробовать ручками добавить:

```
XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create("imported.xsd");
XmlSchema s = XmlSchema.Read(r, null);
document.Schemas.Add(s);
```

То валидация пройдет успешно, но это не вариант, т.к. файлы и схемы всегда разные.

Comment: А покажите как у вас импортируются схемы.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Да как бы даже не совсем у меня... `<xs:import namespace="urn:customs.ru:Information:EArchDocuments:EADCommonTypes:5.13.1" schemaLocation="EADCommonTypes.xsd" />` . В вопросе имена файлов указаны абстрактные, по факту же рядом с основной схемой лежит, конечно же, именно `EADCommonTypes.xsd`.

Comment: [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48910255/5376639) рекомендуют писать свой резолвер. А [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10178944/5376639) указывать правильный контекст